# How to exclude specific test in wdio.conf.js

Tags: selenium, webdriver-io

I'm successfully excluding a whole feature file from my chrome runs, using the code below, but I have one specific test in a different feature file failing. I want to exclude the one failing scenario rather than the whole file.  Is this possible?

```
capabilities: [
    {
       os: "Windows",
       os_version: "10",
       browser: "Chrome",
       exclude: [
         'features/myfeature.feature',
         'my failing scenario',
       ],
     },
],
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible to exclude scenarios in that way. Instead, you could use tags to skip a particular scenario, similar to [how it's done via the cucumber-boilerplate webdriverio project](https://github.com/webdriverio/cucumber-boilerplate/blob/master/wdio.conf.js#L166):

```
cucumberOpts: {
    tagExpression: 'not @Pending',
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You may add tag to this scenario e.g. @KnownIssue and exclude this tag by config

```
cucumberOpts:
{
....
tagExpression: "not @KnownIssue"
.....
}
```